# Extracting phone number issue in R

Tags: regex, r

Having numbers like this:

```
ll <- readLines(textConnection("(412) 573-7777 opt 1
563.785.1655 x1797
(567) 523-1534 x7753
(567) 483-2119 x 477
(451) 897-MALL
(342) 668-6255 ext 7
(317) 737-3377 Opt 4
(239) 572-8878 x 3
233.785.1655 x1776
(138) 761-6877 x 4
(411) 446-6626 x 14
(412) 337-3332x19
412.393.3177 x24
327.961.1757 ext.4"))
```

What is the regex I should write to get:

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

I tried this one:

```
gsub('[(]([0-9]{3})[)] ([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4}).*','\\1-\\2-\\3',ll)
```

It doesn't cover all the possibilities. I think I can do it using several regex patterns, but I think it can be done using a single regex.

Comment: What about the one with `MALL`? `MALL` is not a number.

Comment: @stribizhev - `1800 PIZZA` etc are phone numbers, groups of letters correspond to numbers on the keypad.

Comment: @stribizhev ah good catch. The idea is to extract the maximum of elements that respect this pattern.

Comment: Also relevant: [a comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to extract numbers that are represented with letters, you can use the following regex in `gsub`:

```
gsub('[(]?([0-9]{3})[)]?[. -]([A-Z0-9]{3})[. -]([A-Z0-9]{4}).*','\\1-\\2-\\3',ll)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Prwutj)

You can remove all `A-Z` from character classes to just match numbers with no letters.

**REGEX**:

- `[(]?` - An optional `(`
- `([0-9]{3})` - 3 digits
- `[)]?` - An optional `)`
- `[. -]` - Either a dot, or a space, or a hyphen
- `([A-Z0-9]{3})` - 3 digit or letter sequence
- `[. -]` - Either a dot, or a space, or a hyphen
- `([A-Z0-9]{4})` - 4 digit or letter sequence
- `.*` - Any number of characters to the end