# Writing a function to return the nth group of numbers in a phone number

Tags: r

For example,  function should be: `function_name(phonenumber, n)`

- `function_name(123-456-7890, 1)` should return 123
- `function_name((123)-456-7890, 3)` should return 7890

Comment: What did you try? Where are you getting stuck? How many different number types do you need to match? Does this help give you a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172751/extracting-phone-number-issue-in-r

Comment: broncos24, you are welcome on SO, but you are starting to show a pattern that is not really aligned to the "norm" on StackOverflow (at least within [tag:r] channels). (1) Please *accept* answers (not just upvoting them). (2) Do some research on your own first, please do not treat "asking a question on SO" as your first web-search. (3) When you do ask a question, please provide (much) more than just terse requirements, including sample data, intended output, and the code you've attempted before now. You're very welcome here, but please respect our volunteered time.

Answer (score 3):

```r
function_name <- function(phone, n) Filter(nzchar, strsplit(phone, "\\D+")[[1]])[n]
function_name("123-456-7890", 1)
# [1] "123"
function_name("(123)-456-7890", 3)
# [1] "7890"
```

Answer (score 2):

One base R option is using `regmatches`

```
function_name <- function(phonenumber, n) regmatches(phonenumber,gregexpr("\\d+",phonenumber))[[1]][n]
```

Comment: I think this one is likely a little more robust to strings that don't look like phone numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `\\w+` or `\\d+` :

```
get_nth_group <- function(x, n) stringr::str_extract_all(x, '\\w+')[[1]][n]

get_nth_group("123-456-7890", 1)
#[1] "123"

get_nth_group("(123)-456-7890", 3)
#[1] "7890"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split by `-` and then extract the 'nth' group

```
f1 <- function(phonenumber, n){
             setdiff(strsplit(phonenumber, '[[:punct:]]+')[[1]], "")[n]
    }

f1('123-456-7890', 3)
#[1] "7890"

f1('(123)-456-7890', 3)
#[1] "7890"
```

Comment: @broncos24 sorry, didn't see that case.  Updated the post. thanks for notifying

Comment: is there a way to do it with str_detect or str_view

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

get_phone_group <- function(phonenum, n) {
  str_extract_all(phonenum, "\\d+", simplify = TRUE)[, n]
}

get_phone_group("123-456-7890", 1)
#> [1] "123"
get_phone_group("(123)-456-7890", 3)
#> [1] "7890"
get_phone_group(c("345-169-234", "(123)-456-7890"), 3)
#> [1] "234"  "7890"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that the resulting function is vectorized and therefore nice to use in e.g. a `mutate` context.